# Julia 1.7.2 : how to use @sprintf

Tags: julia, printf, julia-1.7

I am new to julia 1.7.2.  I found on julialang.org about @sprintf.
I try to show a number 45 as:  00045

```
a = @sprintf "%05i" 45           # I get:  @sprintf not defined

a = Printf.@sprintf "%05i" 45    # I get:  Printf not defined
```

What is missing in this 1 line program? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the `Printf` module first. For example with `using` (in which case you do not need to prefix `@sprintf` with `Printf`):

```
julia> using Printf

julia> @sprintf "%05i" 45
"00045"
```